# How to find subsequent (all) SLOT from a subclass

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I need to block specific buttons on an MMI.
I implemented a button blocking function in a subclass of QPushButton.
For this, I used the clicked() signal and blocked the button with blockSignals(true).
This means that with each button clicked on my MMI, 2 SLOTS are always called.
But when calling the blocking of a specific button, I get the first SLOT (clicked()) of my subclass, in which I block the button, then I then arrive in the original SLOT linked to this button, which is still called despite the blocking (the first time only).
How can I in my QPushButton subclass know the subsequent SLOTs linked to this button and avoid them (delete them)?

```
void QbtnStandardButton::slotButtonClicked(void)
{
    if (modeProtection)
    {
        // Special mode to protect/unprotect the button
        if (isProtected())
        {
            // Reset the protection
            this->blockSignals(false);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the protection: button will be unclickable
            this->blockSignals(true);
        }
        modeProtection = false;
    }
    if (isProtected())
    {
        QMessageBox *pMsgBox = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Information,
                                  "Protection",
                                  "This button is protected!",
                                  QMessageBox::Ok);
        pMsgBox->exec();
        pMsgBox->deleteLater();
        // Here: remove subsequent SLOT of this button ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very difficult if not impossible to find SLOTS linked to a button.
I worked around the problem by using an eventFilter() instead of a SIGNAL() in my base class.
In this case, I can filter the "clicked()" event before it is reissued.